# Why is my DataGrid showing up in the wrong Grid column?

Tags: c#, wpf

My DataGrid should be showing up in the middle of three Grid columns, Column 1, but instead it appears to be showing up in Column 0, as seen here:

[image: DataGrid in Column 0 instead of Column 1]

You can see there that my Cancel button (Column 0) and my OK button (column 2) are right next to each other because the DataGrid appears to be occupying Column 0, instead of Column 1. However, when I break my code during execution and do `Grid.GetColumn(DataGridFilteredFixesReportsTable)`, it properly returns 1.

I've also tried moving the DataGrid to Column 2 to see what happens, but the visual result was exactly the same.

What am I doing wrong or misunderstanding about how this works?

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid Margin="20,20,20,20" Name="SettingsGrid" Visibility="Visible">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MaxHeight="600"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
              Name="DataGridFilteredFixesReportsTable" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FilteredFixesReportsTable.DefaultView}"
              DataContext="{Binding ElementName=SeeAllFixesReportsWindow}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="True"
              FontSize="28" FontFamily="Times New Roman"
              IsReadOnly="True">
            </DataGrid>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" 
            Name="ButtonCancel" 
            Click="OkCancel_Click" 
            Content="Cancel" 
            FontSize="32" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" Background="Pink"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" 
            Name="ButtonOk" 
            IsDefault="True" 
            Click="OkCancel_Click" 
            Content="OK" 
            FontSize="32" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" Background="PaleGreen"/>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct children of the `Grid` should have the column and row specifications. Your `DataGrid` is a child of `ScrollViewer`, not `Grid` so it is ignoring those properties.

Try:

```xaml
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid Margin="20,20,20,20" Name="SettingsGrid" Visibility="Visible">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MaxHeight="600"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- Should be set here -->
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <DataGrid 
              Name="DataGridFilteredFixesReportsTable" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FilteredFixesReportsTable.DefaultView}"
              DataContext="{Binding ElementName=SeeAllFixesReportsWindow}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="True"
              FontSize="28" FontFamily="Times New Roman"
              IsReadOnly="True">
            </DataGrid>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" 
            Name="ButtonCancel" 
            Click="OkCancel_Click" 
            Content="Cancel" 
            FontSize="32" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" Background="Pink"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" 
            Name="ButtonOk" 
            IsDefault="True" 
            Click="OkCancel_Click" 
            Content="OK" 
            FontSize="32" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" Background="PaleGreen"/>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Since it isn't set on the `ScrollViewer` it is defaulting to 0 and 0 for row and column.

Comment: Concisely and well explained. Thank you!